# Send Message through SSH

Tags: ssh

How would one can send a message to the logged in user's desktop through ssh? I sometimes connect my friend's computer to help him out, but i need to the a message to his *desktop* rather than using `talk` or `ytalk`.

There are options like `notify-send`, `gmessage`, `xmessage`. But since I'm connected with `SSH` I cannot connect to their desktop.

Setting environment variable `DISPLAY` does not work as well.

How do I  that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just setting $DISPLAY is not enough for *xmessage* since you don't have the needed authentication data for connecting to another user's X11 server – you would need to copy $XAUTHORITY as well. For *notify-send*, only $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is required, but you will likely be denied access by the DBus policy.

Use [this script](https://raw.github.com/grawity/code/master/misc/envcp) to copy environment variables easily, and use `sudo` to run the command under your friend's account. For example:

```
pid=$(pgrep -x -u jon gnome-session)
sudo -u jon ./envcp $pid notify-send 'Hi'
```

(Instead of `gnome-session` any other process of that user can be used.)

Comment: seems a bit long way to use, i'll try to make a bash script for that